# How can I collapse content with a Bootstrap toggle button (checkbox)?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Using **Bootstrap 5.1** I have some buttons that hide/show some content using the **collapse** plugin

```
    <div class="col m-2">
         <button type="btn" class="btn btn-outline-primary m-1" 
data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#focus_id">Focus
         </button>
    </div>
```

However there is nothing to indicate to the user if a button has been pressed or not, I want them to be toggle buttons. According to the documentation this is done by setting

```
data-bs-toggle="button"
```

but I am already using this to hide/show content with

```
data-bs-toggle="collapse"
```

So how do I do both, I tried

```
   data-bs-toggle="button,collapse"
```

but that didn't work

**Update**

I used Davids idea, but struggling to get Boostrap to keep the toggle so instead renamed the button, added the following javascript to the page

```
let movementsSection = document.getElementById('movements_id')
let movementsButton  = document.getElementById('show_movements_button')
if(movementsSection!=null)
{
    movementsSection.addEventListener('show.bs.collapse', function() {movementsButton.innerText='Hide Movements';});
    movementsSection.addEventListener('hide.bs.collapse', function() {movementsButton.innerText='Show Movements';});
}
```

This works okay, except the fact I have hardcoded the button names into the Javascript which is going to cause problems when I internationize the code.

The html code is generated but the Javascript is not, would be better if I could implement a solution within the html itself.

Comment: A toggler is a dual-state control. You'd have write some custom scripting to handle synchronization of the toggler and the collapse element. Bootstrap probably won't do it out of the box. What have you tried?

Comment: I cant understand what is your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

> However there is nothing to indicate to the user if a button has been pressed or not

Well, the fact that the collapsible section is hidden or shown should be enough of an indicator!

Anyways, I guess since the two components share the same attribute you should go the manual way and the easiest way - at least from a maintenance point of view, is adding an eventListener to your collapsible section:

```
let collapsibleSection = document.getElementById('mySection');
let toggleButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
collapsibleSection.addEventListener('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
    if (toggleButton.classList.contains('my-active-css-class') {
        toggleButton.classList.add('your-inactive-css-class');
        toggleButton.classList.remove('your-active-css-class');
    }
});
collapsibleSection.addEventListener('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
    if (toggleButton.classList.contains('my-inactive-css-class') {
        toggleButton.classList.add('your-active-css-class');
        toggleButton.classList.remove('your-inactive-css-class');
    }
});
```

Please note that these two events are fired **after** the transition completion. If you want your code to be triggered as soon as the user clicks on the button, use the `show.bs.collapse` and the `hide.bs.collapse` events instead [See relevant part of documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/collapse/#events); beware though that method calls on **transitioning component will be ignored** ([relevant docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/javascript/#asynchronous-functions-and-transitions)).

Comment: the collapsible section may not even be visible on screen, okay thx im not sure where that code goes is it a javascript function ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor yes, it's javascript. I know libraries like BS (ah, funny acronyms...) may give you the impression you can make interactive pages without knowing javascript, but that's true only until it is not! I suggest you dive into javascript ASAP. :)

Comment: i know its javascript but where does it go, i have written simple javascript functions but this isnt a function, so I dont understand what calls it, or does it just sit on the html page and get called when the event occurs

Comment: It is a function indeed (two, actually), only it's being called by the element it is attached to when the event is triggered. It's pretty basic functionality. Good practices dictate you put that code in separate .js file and reference it in your DOM through a `<script src="source.js"></script>` element. Since this is short you can put it directly between the tags with no `src` attribute, but once you start using javascript these scripts tends to grow pretty fast... best practices from then beginning is always better.

Comment: Hmm, i can see now there are tow functions defined, however the whole is not a function, the first line let collapsibleSection = document.getElementById('mySection'); is not within a function is it, thats what im finding confusing.

Comment: That is a simple variable declaration. Look, I don't want to be rude or scoff at you, but that is such a basic concept that one can tell you're entering in a territory you don't know nothing about. That's why I told you that you should consider diving into both core and client-side javascript if you want to keep at this. Cheers!

Comment: Actually I do know more than you think, but your answer is a bit half baked, whilst useful it doesnt give the full answer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the first issue that you have mentioned:

> there is nothing to indicate to the user if a button has been pressed or not

CSS only solution can be used

```
button.collapsed:focus:not(:active) {
      background-color: navy;
}
```

As for swapping the text/label of the button - that is more difficult and requires building a custom element. As @Davide tried to explain to you. Basically the functionality you would like does not come out-of-box with bootstrap.
Davide's code is valid and yes, the first 2 lines are decplarations, while the one starting with 'collapsibleSection.addEvent...' is a function, there are 2 of them here. What they do is they add Event Listener - sort of a sensor that is waiting for a specific trigger, in this case 'hidden.bs.collapse' - if triggered - it executes the function with 3 lines of code.

As for the fact whether this is halp baked solution - well, your requirements are quite high, especially if you need the button label to be (programatically, I assume?) internationized.

What one could do is to add a html element with labels, then have JS to take those labels and swap them based on a trigger - basically a more advanced version of what Davide has proposed.

Comment: I didn't really want the text to be changed and I didn't ask davide for this, but I have ended up doing that because I couldn't get the toggle button to indicate permanently that it was toggled. The solution was half baked in the sense it wan't clear to me where to put the javascript that was written but I have worked that out now. But I will now try your solution, looks simper.